# system call lseek causing segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have an exec file that I know there is one (or more) appearances of the string "coolyo" in it, and need to copy this file and replace all appearances of "coolyo" with the argument my program received " using system calls.
I have got an entry and the system_call funciton written in assembly.

However, when I write my argument as something with same length as "coolyo" (6), it works and everything is fine, it replaces it. If I enter an argument to replace "coolyo" with whose length is less or more than 6, it gives segmentation fault when trying to run the file.

What is the problem?

And on the way, two more questions:

1. do systemcalls `sys_read` and `sys_write` change the file pointers according to how many bytes I received/sent? (if so, there shouldn't be a problem! but there is!)
2. when I do sys_read 5 bytes, then re-do sys_read 5 bytes, after the first call, where is the file pointer? at place 5? or at place 1? Meaning, does the second sys_read read from file[1] or file[4]?

My code:

```
int filePtr=-1;
while(filePtr!=0) {
    char buf[6];
    filePtr=system_call(SYS_READ,newfile,buf,6);
    if(strcmp(buf,"coolyo")==0) {
        system_call(SYS_WRITE,fd,argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        system_call(SYS_LSEEK,fd,strlen(argv[1]) - 5, 1);
    }
    else
        system_call(SYS_WRITE,fd,buf,5);
}
```

Comment: If the argument is shorter and only strings are being manipulated, why don't you just pad it with nulls?

Comment: Then life gets much more challenging.  I don't entirely follow what you are trying but if you are trying to edit a compiled executable then realize the compiler will have created many constants based on the memory layout that need to be updated when things change size.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Read and write advance the file position by the number of bytes read or written
2. system calls return negative on failure, which your code doesn't handle
3. you approach will find only "coolyo" that are aligned on 6-byte boundaries
4. your write call when "coolyo" isn't found is writing only five bytes, but you read 6
5. The read syscall will not append a NUL character, which strcmp needs